# How do I prevent overwriting information in a text file with the ofstream?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning C++ and I was trying to add text to a file, but it keeps overwriting it, is there anyway I can append stuff to it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ofstream fil3;
    fil3.open("test.txt");
    file3 << " bye!"; // replaces text already existing in file :(
    fil3.close();
    return 0;

}
```

So, I already have a text file with the words "Good" in it and I wanna try adding "bye!" to it so I have "Good Bye!". Can someone explain to me what function I should be using here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open the file, use the append flag:

```
file3.open("test.txt", std::ofstream::app);
```

You can read more about file operation options [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on google, is there anything I can search up to elarn more about file related stuff? My c++ guide book only teaches me to write and read from files. >.>

Comment: See my edit for file operation options, if you want general information about c++ http://en.cppreference.com/w/ is a fantastic resource.